# create a from and show entered details in another page in orchard cms

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

just created a from using "custom form" with input fields like - "Title", "Caption", "Alternate Text", and a button called "Submit". After `submit` i need to show the entered input fields as an output in another page. How can i achieve this.
Pls guide me with step by step solution. I am not a developer, Im just a designer

Answer (score 0):

So, you created a custom type and added those fields.
Then created a custom form with this type.

You can configure the form to redirect after submit thanks to an textbox that allows to use Tokens, i.e dynamic information retrieved by the content.
Thanks to this, you should be able to redirect to the display url of the content.

To display the output the way you want in another page, you need to make an override of your content in your theme.
You can enable the 'Shape tracing' feature to generate this alternate view of your content and then modify it as you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i ve created an alternate view.
For ex. I ve two form submissions like url's, 
1. localhost:34370/Contents/Item/Display/125
2. localhost:34370/Contents/Item/Display/124
and
I ve created an alternate view say: Content-AddUser.cshtml
in that page how can i get the both page (ids:124 and 125) details pls share the sample code.

Comment: created an alternate view, i have submitted the custom form for two times with form details like Title: Hello and another Title: World.
Where as in Content-AddUser.cshtml shows only Title "World".
I am expecting like
Title: Hello
Title: World
Pls help me in this problem
Sorry for my english